# Recommendations for finite element textbook?

Tags: reference-request, finite-element-method

I am looking for a nice book for learning the mathematical theory of finite element methods. The book should be accessible to students who are familiar with basic real analysis and Lebesgue theory, but perhaps less familiar with partial differential equations. Some topics that such a book might include would be: $L^p$ spaces, distribution theory, Sobolev spaces, Hilbert Spaces, etc, in a fair amount of detail.

Comment: Try https://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Finite-Element-Analysis-Hutton/dp/0072395362

Comment: If you want something from theory point of view, prof. Hope has a good set of pdfs  https://www.math.uh.edu/~rohop/Fall_16/index.html

Comment: A standard work for civil engineers and it's even online: [The Finite Element Method](http://www.iauyazd.ac.ir/iauyazd/UserFiles/File/OmranGroup/files/Zienkiewicz%20O_C_,%20Taylor%20R_L_%20Vol_%201_%20The%20finite%20element%20met.pdf) by O.C. Zienkiewicz et al.

Comment: Some topics that such a book might include? I would strongly discourage all of those overly mathematical treatments of finite element methods and recommend __studying the real thing__ instead.